# How to read CQ5 content node under jcr:content on selectionchanged event

Tags: aem

I have requirement to design a page with two controls

1. drop down list
2. rich text box.

The rich text box value is dependent on selected drop down value. I.e Based on the drop down selected item, a node value (under `content/mypage/jcr:content`) to be read into the rich text box.

I got from few sites that we can achieve this through the `listener` `selectionchanged` event. However I am struggling to read the node value and assign it to the rich text box.

Can anyone please guide me or provide an example which meets my requirement?